# How to avoid plotting of the title in SOM's plot.kohonen function

Tags: r, som, self-organizing-maps

I am using plot function from the kohonen package in R. The function inherently produces title called "property plot" or whatever different plot I specify. I can change the name and customize it but I am not able to alter its size.

I want to either remove the inherent title plotting or increase the size of the title.

I have attached a plot in which there are two different titles. The smaller one is the inherent one and the larger one is added through title function. The code for the same is also given
[image]

```
plot(knime.model, type = "property", property = unscaled, main = colnames(knime.model$data)[5], , cex = 2, font.main= 4 palette.name=coolBlueHotRed, heatkey = F,  ncolors = length(unique(data[,5])))
title(colnames(knime.model$data)[5], cex.main = 3)
```

Comment: Try `par(cex.main=3) ;plot(knime.model, type="counts",main="Test")` or write in your plot function only `main=""`to suppress the title.